# DLL Access Error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found - QuickBooks SDK

Tags: asp.net, dll, com, interop, quickbooks

I have an ASP.NET application that interacts with the QuickBooks SDK for desktop.

When the following code is executed on our target server (at a hosting company):

```
QBSessionManager SessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
```

I'm getting the error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BF97F9A2-A475-4F26-9B5B-3A14F02D9824} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This error does not occur on my local machine - the QB-related code has been fully tested on my local machine.

The application is .NET Framework 4.7.2.
The platform target is set to x86.
The QB SDK version is 8.0.
The problem server is Windows Server 2019.

Interop.QBFC8.dll and qbfc8.dll were installed with the SDK installer.
They are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks.
They are not blocked.
Interop.QBFC8.dll is in the GAC.

In my code I added a check for InProcServer32:

```
string clsid = "{BF97F9A2-A475-4F26-9B5B-3A14F02D9824}";
RegistryKey t_clsidKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID");
RegistryKey t_clsidSubKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID\\" + clsid + "\\InProcServer32");
```

When run on the server it returns C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\qbfc8.dll.

The related registry keys/values for CLSID {BF97F9A2-A475-4F26-9B5B-3A14F02D9824} and QBFC8.QBSessionManager all match what I have on my local machine.  I can provide those.

It's a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit machine, so it's doing the Wow6432Node registry entries - they look OK.

We've tried raising permissions on C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks - this had no effect.

We ran Process Monitor when running a test to the server.  We saw no Registry Access Errors.  We saw Interop.QBFC8.dll and qbfc8.dll both being accessed, seemingly without error.

We tried setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" in IIS to both True/False - same error.

I've been plagued by this thing for a month.  If anyone out there has any suggestions, I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: Does not a copy of quickbooks also need to be installed on the computer running the qb sdk?

Comment: @AlbertDKallal  I don't think so.  I hope not, I don't think I could do that.

Comment: I seem to recall that yes, you require QB to be installed on any workstation that you using the SDK interface + .net code to interface with QB. I mean, that SDK allows you to do things like create a invoice or whatever, and that kind of functionally requires a full copy of QB to be installed on the same computer running that SDK created code. I mean, do a test of a tiny wee bit of code - say some code to pull a company from QB. Remember, that is a COM object automation interface, and it not unlike how say we could create a instance of Excel or word to THEN automate its functions.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal The client needs QB and the QB Web Connector (QBWC).  QBWC has entries that point to the URL of code on the server.  That server code points to the SDK on the server.

Comment: You not using web connector if you using QBFC8. (that is very old by the way, and about 5 years ago, I was using QBFC13).  So, web connector is a VERY different issue + story. But, for QBFC8 code? yes, you need QB installed on same computer. For web connector? Web connector is as noted a 100% different story, different use case, and not related in any way to using QBFC library code. So, if you only use web connector, then you can dump use of QBFC8 code.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal I know QBFC8 is old, the QB interface is from an older system - the main task was to update the main system to .CORE MVC, so I was avoiding any possible update headaches.  Although, who knows, maybe upgrading to a more recent version would somehow solve this.
On the rest - I'm not sure where you're getting your info, but that QB interface code is sitting on another server right now - it's QBFC8 and the client uses QBWC and has for a few years now.  So - y'know - sure seems like QBFC8 uses QBWC.
Have you ever used QBFC8?

Comment: The fact of "older" is a non issue. The simple matter is QBFC requires QuickBooks to be installed on the same computer such code runs at. That's the first issue you have to deal. QBFC might and can "also" use the web connector, but it don't matter since you need QB installed on the same computer running QBFC (at least that I what I recall). You can perhaps get around this issue by using the web connector running on that server or another computer dedicated for that, and then use QBWC. You using COM automation here when you use QBFC, and that means QB has to be installed on same computer.

Comment: Did not think .net core supports use of COM objects (unmanaged code). it might, but the whole idea of .net core is to dump and not use un-managed code.  I not looked at the SDK in about 5 years, so maybe there is a newer updated version for .net core, but I doubt it. You should however in theory be able to use the web connector, but again, I don't know if .net core supports calling + using un-managed code. So, yes, I have used QBFC (don't matter if it is version 8 or 13 - they work the same). And no, we did not use the QBWC. They look similar, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal The QB interface code is in a separate ASP.NET web service project, it's not CORE.

I just think you're wrong about QB needing to be installed on the server.  The QBFC install should put all that's necessary on the server.  The Web Connector doesn't run on the server, it runs on the client - it has the web service URL, connects to the server using that.

.NET uses an Interop wrapper to handle COM objects.  The Interop dll is "managed", and then the COM is found through CLSID.

Comment: When using QBFC? Yes, then a full copy of QB has to be installed on the SAME computer as the software using QBFC. You see/get a security prompt when this occurs. So, context is required here. If you using the bridge or web connector then no. See the post of mine below for the security prompt you get/see and have to deal with the first time you try to using QBFC with QuickBooks. The screen cap in my post below shows that security certificate. So, it going to depend on how the QBFC interface is being used, but yes, it will require a full working copy of QuickBooks to be installed on that pc.

Answer (score 0):

To use the QBFC system with QuickBooks desktop, and not the web connector, or "RDS" server, then you reqiure a full edition of QuickBooks desktop when using the QBFC interface.

In fact, the first time you do this, QuickBooks desktop will show this:

[image]

As you can see in above, the security prompt can allow the QBFC interface to run if you not launched (have) QB running, but what occures is a copy is started if you don't have it running already.

So, "context" here is required. The QBFC interface system has two choices, and in fact in later editions they have removed the web connector part(s), and you are to use web api calls as a result.

However, for interface(s) using the QBFC and not some "connector" technology, then YES you do need to have a full edition of QuickBooks installed on the same computer running QBFC.

As noted, the first time such a application written using the QBFC interface is run, then the user in QuickBooks will see/get and HAVE to answer + deal with the above security prompt.

So, part of this answer "depends" on how the QBFC interface code was written and being used, but for the most part, QBFC will require a full working copy of QuickBooks to be installed on the same computer.

As noted, exceptions are is a RDS server - or the point of sale interface (if that's what you doing with the QBFC + sdk). And the other possible is using the web connector.

However, assuming a 100% desktop enviorment? Then yes, to use QBFC in this limited context, yes, you need a full working copy of QB on that same computer running your interface code written using .net and the SDK.

So, the answer is it "depends" on what and how the SDK is being used to interface with QB. And depending on that "how" will thus determine if you need full QB installed to work with the QBFC interface or not.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal  In this scenario - what component is pointing to the .NET application that uses QBFC?

Comment: Anything in the. Net application that uses the qbfc library code would trigger the above dialog in qb. And note the option that qb must be running.  And if you choose the option allow even if qb not running it will start qb running. So anything in the. Net code that's not based on web connecter would thus be using qb application as a com object. Not really any different than say creating a copy of outlook in vb code to create a email,  or say word automation from .net code.  Your. Net code has to be talking to something or interfaces directly to a copy of qb

Comment: Ask the following simple question-- did that desktop .net code ever run or be used on a desktop computer without qb installed? A really simple question you need to answer.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-quickbooks-web-connector

Comment: @AlbertDKallal QB and QBWC are on the CLIENT!!  QB must be open on the CLIENT. QBFC8.dll, Interop.QBFC8.dll and the .NET QB interface (web service) are on the SERVER.

Comment: Correct, I said YOU MUST provide a context here. If you uisng a web connector, then fine, but if you not using a web connector, then yes you need QB installed on the same computer. If you setup a web connector running on another computer, then yes this can work. If you not setup a computer running the web connector service, and are using QBFC to create a session + update information into QB, then yes, you need full QB.  So, if you running a web connector on another computer, sure, you don't need QB installed on that computer. I mean, think about this - what/where are those commands being sent?

Comment: And when you say "client", that needs context here. The client STILL has to be on the same network - the web server applicaation can't use the browser + to communicate with the client computer running web connector. You need a direct connection from the QBFC code to the web connector - and IIS and web site to client side will not suffice in this case. You not going to be running the web connector on a bunch of computers, but only a computer with full QB installed. The computer running web connector needs QB in this example.

Comment: You come to my site to look at some cute cat pictures. Your web server now can't muck around on my computer and steal my files, or connect to a local copy running say SQL server. Hitting the web site with a browser does not given ANY use of resources or services on MY computer. That would mean no one would use the web due to security concerns. A user hitting the web site is using a browser - the web server has NO means to touch or talk to ANYTHING else running on my computer. If the web site and spcific here code behind using QBFC uses web connector running on a specific computer then fine.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal The whole point of the Web Connector is to connect from a client (running QBWC and QB with QB open) to a server with the .NET web service and QBFC8.  It's right there in the name - WEB CONNECTOR.

Comment: Yes, I get that - was there a new point you making here? I stated unless the QBFC interface is using a web connector, then  you need QB installed on that same computer running the QBFC interface. If you running a web connector on some computer, then QBFC can use that, and you don't need QB installed (on same computer where QBFC code is ruining). And telling me the web connector allows other computers to connect using web connector? Sure, you can do that too, but that has VERY little to do with you having a web site application written in .net. So once again I'm failing to see your point here?

Comment: So, are you running both the web connector service, and also a web site written in .net, or are you talking about ONLY the web connector being run here? Code behind in the asp .net site can use QBFC and we assume it connecting to a computer running the web connector (that computer needs QB installed). However, again, that has next to zero to do with a user + browser hitting your asp.net web site application.  it is the code behind on the web site that running QBFC, and that setup does not allow some connecting to your client computer (unless it assumed to be on same network).

Comment: @AlbertDKallal I appreciate the time you're spending here, but it's not helping me.

Comment: It should help. You have to determine if the QBFC code is using and connecting to a web connector or not. If it is not, then you need QB installed on that server. I would build a small test desktop project that pulls say a company name or invoice. And then try running that stand alone little .net exe program on that server and see if it works.  So,  2 possible issues here. Either its permissions of the IIS user that runs the .net code. Creating  a tiny stand alone test program to see if QBFC is working on that server. If it works then IIS user permissions, if not then web connector is issue.